# ffmpeg make ERROR: avisynth/avisynth_c.h avisynth/avs/version.h not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I use mingw64 to compile ffmpeg on msys2 --enable-avisynth prompts an error

```
ffmpeg make ERROR: avisynth/avisynth_c.h avisynth/avs/version.h not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that AviSynth+ is used after ffmpeg5.0, we need to use cmake to recompile AviSynth+, and put the generated AviSynth into minw64/include
[image]